# vue-datepicker calendar select button is disabled on "max-date"

Tags: nuxtjs3, vuepic-vue-datepicker

I'm using NuxtJS3 and making use of the min-date and max-date. The days show as expected and i am able to click on them, however, on the max-date, the select button is disabled. Any idea why this could be happening? See screenshot below.

Code

```
<VueDatePicker v-model="date" :disabled-week-days="[6, 0]" :min-date="minDate" :max-date="maxDate"></VueDatePicker>
```

Versions -

Vue-datepicker

```
"@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^7.2.2",
```

NuxtJS 3

```
"nuxt": "^3.7.4",
```

I have been able to replicate issue on playground (refer to screenshot) -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because the max. date argument defined like yours is constructed at midnight. The time of 15:30 is already outside of the range.

Pass like this to make the whole day allowed:

`:max-date="new Date('2023-11-24 23:59:59')"`

Comment: Beautiful! thank you @Ellrohir!